# Angular JS not rendering HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I wrote a simple Angular code but the HTML is not rendering correctly or the expression is not getting evaluated. Please help with what i am missing. I am using angular.min.js minified(1.6).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {
            var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant',
               'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];

            $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
            };
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>
        <h2>Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length}}</h2>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ng-controller` ? `var app` ? `app.controller` ?

Comment: Read the angular docs to get started..https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Click to start learning http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

Comment: @Rayon - Im sorry. But i didnt quiet get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a root for your application with the `ng-app` directive and create a controller for your app from which you can handle the `$scope`:

```js
var app = angular.module("ng-app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant', 'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];
  $scope.ourEmployees = employees;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ng-app">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h2>Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```